# How to add a new column in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say I want to add a 4th column to a 3x3 matrix filled with ones.

```
% random 3x3 matrix
matrix = randi([1 10],3,3);
```

I know how to add a new row filled with ones:

```
matrix = [matrix;ones(1,3)]
```

but when I try adding a new column either like this:

```
matrix =[ones(3,1) matrix]
```

or like that:

```
matrix = [ones(3,1);matrix]
```

I get error about matrices not being consistent.

Comment: `matrix = [ones(3,1) matrix]` does not error.

Comment: `matrix =[ones(3,1) matrix]` should work but notice that you are storing the result in the same variable, so if you run it again matrix will no longer be a 3x3. You have probably executed it once wrong and now matrix is not 3x3. Try storing the result in a new variable for testing: `matrix2 = [ones(3,1) matrix]` or clearing the variable every time you run the code.

Comment: Also if possible try pre-allocating the matrix with the final size. Otherwise adding a column or row might be slow (speacially if you do this a lot of times)

Answer (score 2):

Your code stores the output in the same variable you used as input.

This is dangerous if you don't take care.

Example:

```
matrix = randi([1 10],3,3);   % Here matrix is 3x3

matrix = [matrix; ones(1,3)];  % we add a row, now matrix is 4x3

matrix =[ones(3,1) matrix];    % here we cannot add a 3x1 column since matrix is 4x3
```

You can always add debugging code to understand what is happening.

```
matrix = randi([1 10],3,3);    % Here matrix is 3x3
matrix = [matrix; ones(1,3)];  % we add a row, now matrix is 4x3
disp size(matrix);             % will show you that matrix is no longer 3x3
matrix =[ones(3,1) matrix];
```